# SearchView AutoComplete is appearing with Black border and covering the searchtext?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, autocomplete, searchview

[Image how the searchView autocomplete is appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydQHX.jpg)

The searchView AutoComplete is appearing with black border as shown in image and I haven't made any custom layout still it is showing that black border and hiding the text.Below the code is also attached that I have used.`

```
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            this.menu = menu;
            menuItem =  menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
            searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);


            menuItem.setVisible(false);

            final SearchView.SearchAutoComplete searchAutoComplete =
                    searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);

            searchAutoComplete.setDropDownBackgroundResource(android.R.color.white);
            searchAutoComplete.setDropDownAnchor(R.id.action_search);
            ArrayAdapter<String> searchadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                   android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                    all_products);
            searchAutoComplete.setAdapter(searchadapter);
    `
```

Menu Code  It is the Item that is used for opening search option.

```
 <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

AppBar layout Code It is the code made for Creating the App Action Bar But how this is affecting the search autocomplete to appear black border around it and hiding the search text.

```
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/CustomActionBar">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Avrutti Electronics"/>


            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar4"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"/>
            <requestFocus />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Your layout code maybe??

Comment: @Sdghasemi I have attached the layout code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found my Question answer It is problem because I was trying to override the theme Appcompat.light through 
searchAutoComplete.setDropDownBackgroundResource(android.R.color.white);
So as soon as I removed this statement the border was removed.

Comment: Thanks sir you save today my job

Answer (score 0):

From my observations, this is caused by the theme you're using `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar`. Change your themes to something that have `...Light.ActionBar` in its its name Or simply modify your theme in `styles.xml` and add the following snippet to it.

```
<item name="android:dropDownItemStyle">@style/myDropDownItemStyle</item>
<item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/myDropDownListViewStyle</item>
```

Comment: I have done as you said but its not working any other problem you observe

Comment: What is the parent theme for `CustomActionBar`?

Comment: ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar I have used ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light also but its not changing anything